# Calculating cumsum in python across two dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Subject Session Trial   Choice
1          1       1    A
1          1       2    B
1          1       3    B
1          2       1    B
1          2       2    B
2          1       1    A
```

And I want to generate two additional columns-- one that returns a value based on "choice", and one that tracks the cumulative sum of those choices for each session per subject. I would like the output to look like this:

```
Subject Session Trial   Choice Score    Cum Score
1          1       1    A        1       1
1          1       2    B       -1       0
1          1       3    B       -1      -1
1          2       1    B       -1      -1
1          2       2    B       -1      -2
2          1       1    A        1       1
```

I have tried the following, based on answers to similar questions:

```
def change_score(c):
 if c['Chosen'] == A:
   return 1.0
 elif c['Chosen'] == B:
   return -1.0
 else:
   return ''
df1['change_score'] = df1.apply(change_score, axis=1)


df1['Session']=df1['Subject'].apply(lambda x: x[:7])
df1['cumulative_score']=df1.groupby(['Session'])['change_score'].cumsum()
```

This results in the following error: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I'm (obviously) very new to python and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in two steps. The first is to create your `Score` column. Use `np.where`:

```
df['Score'] = np.where(df.Choice == 'A', 1, -1)
df

   Subject  Session  Trial Choice  Score
0        1        1      1      A      1
1        1        1      2      B     -1
2        1        1      3      B     -1
3        1        2      1      B     -1
4        1        2      2      B     -1
5        2        1      1      A      1
```

Alternatively, for more options, use a nested `where`:

```
df['Score'] = np.where(df.Choice == 'A', 1, 
                   np.where(df.Choice == 'B', -1, np.nan)
```

Note that you shouldn't mix string and numeric types in a single column (don't use `''`) if you want performance.

Alternatively, use `np.select`:

```
df['Score'] = np.select([df.Choice == 'A', df.Choice == 'B'], [1, -1])
```

---

Now, generate the `CumScore` column with a `groupby`:

```
df['CumScore'] = df.groupby('Session').Score.cumsum()
df

   Subject  Session  Trial Choice  Score  CumScore
0        1        1      1      A      1         1
1        1        1      2      B     -1         0
2        1        1      3      B     -1        -1
3        1        2      1      B     -1        -1
4        1        2      2      B     -1        -2
5        2        1      1      A      1         0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful and elegant. I would also like to use groupby across both 'Session' and 'Subject', so 'CumScore' begins again when there is a new subject, not just a new session. How could I add that dimension?

Comment: I think I figured this out myself:   df1['CumScore'] = df1.groupby(['Subject','Session']).Score.cumsum()

Comment: @MichaelBarrus Correct, that's how you'd do it.